# sstp-client auto-reconnect in ubuntu

Tags: vpn

I have a remote ubuntu machine that connects via sstp-connect to Microsoft RRAS server. The issue is when Internet connection drops, sstp disconnects and you have to reconnect it manually. How can I force it to retry connection for unlimited amount of time and tries until Internet connection restores?

[VPN is configured via network-manager-sstp-gnome gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41xal.png)